# Config Vars No Save button and key / value disappearing

Tags: heroku

In App section => Settings => Config Vars
I set key value pair.
There is no Save button. I suppose it should save automatically when i don't focus anymore on the field.
I move to Access and come back to Settings, all the key value pair are lost..

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're looking in the right place? The save button [should appear above the variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard), to the right of the "Config Vars" header:

[image: Screenshot hot-linked from Heroku's documentation]

If it still isn't showing up, that sounds like a bug on their side. I suggest you try another browser and / or submit a support request.

In the meantime, you can always [set config vars using the command line](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-cli), e.g.

```
heroku config:set VARIABLE=value
```

That's how I've always done it.